# SQL Compact 4 Entity Framowrk 3.5 upgrade .sdf file

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, upgrade

I have `Windows Forms` Application. I deploy it on client's machine. He use this application localy on his machine. I need to upgrade `database`. How to do this without loosing client's data?

I use `SQL Server` `Compact Edition 4.0` and `Entity Framework 3.5`.

Comment: Just in case, do a backup first ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a script with the required ALTER and INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements, and execute the statements one by one against the customer database (and maybe indicate in a table that the database has been uppgraded in order to run this process only once)

Comment: Thanks ErikEJ. Do you know any free tool which can help to do such a compare? I must say there can be a lot of updates...

Comment: There is that excellent tool made by Erik himself : http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/ there is an editor on which you can drop statements and execute them.

Comment: As Aybe mentions, the SQL CE Toolbox includes a schema compare feature